# Iterating over a Pandas grouped dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas

I am using `groupby` in `pandas` to create some `json` style data. I am having trouble iterating over the grouped `dataframe` as it doesn't recognize my keys

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Group A', 10],
                       ['Group A', 12],
                       ['Group B', 22],
                       ['Group B', 25],
                       ['Group B', 26]],
                  columns = ['Group', 'Value'])

df = df.groupby('Group').agg(['mean', 'count']).reset_index()

json_data = [{'id': row['Group'],
              'name': row['Group'],
              'value': row['mean']} for index, row in df.iteritems()]
print json_data
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'Group'
```

Desired Output:

```
[{
    'id': 'Group A',
    'name': 'Group A',
    'value': 11
}, {
    'id': 'Group B',
    'name': 'Group B',
    'value': 24.33333
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Here's a link to [DataFrame.to_json()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
df = df.groupby('Group').mean().reset_index().rename(columns = {'Group':"id" })
df['name'] = df['id']
df.to_json(orient="records")

'[{"id":"Group A","Value":11.0,"name":"Group A"},{"id":"Group B","Value":24.3333333333,"name":"Group B"}]'
```

You can reorder the JSON output this way:

```
df[['id','name', 'Value', ]].to_json(orient="records")

'[{"id":"Group A","name":"Group A","Value":11.0},{"id":"Group B","name":"Group B","Value":24.3333333333}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html), `iteritems` iterates over the columns (specifically, name/column pairs).  It looks like you want `iterrows`.  (You will still need to change it to access `['Value', 'mean']` rather than `['mean']`, because you created a DataFrame with multiindexed columns.)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to reference `'mean'`. That means sense as `['Value', 'mean']`, but the `Group` column has no label, how is that referenced?

Comment: @user2242044: What do you mean by "has no label"?  The "Group" column can be accessed directly with `["Group"]` as you are already doing, because it doesn't have extra index levels under that.

Comment: @BrenBam, using `row['Group']` seems to be adding the whole dataframe ` Group A
Name: 0, dtype: object,`

Comment: @user2242044: Ah, you're right.  You have to do `row['Group', '']`.